# I try to use set division in oracle but therewas warning message

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-division

```
 select a.studid from student a where not exists(
 (select distinct coursecode  from studentcourse)
 except (select sc.coursecode from studentcourse sc where a.studid=sc.studid));
```

"missing right parenthesis"

i am going to find all student id whose studied all courses in student course,

[geeksforgeeks.org/sql-division](http://geeksforgeeks.org/sql-division)

solution:The oracle sql doesn't support the keyword except,we should replace it by using keyword minus.

Comment: What division? That is an error, not a warning. The query after `except` can't reference the tables prior to `except`. Please explain what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: i am going to find all student id who studied all courses in student course,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-division/

Comment: @HoneyBadger: I think Lee is referring to "relational division"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for you key word"relational division" ,i found the solution already